# Show that $\sum^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{N-1}{i(N-i)}$ is approximately $2\log N$ for large $N$.

Tags: summation, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am working on a problem relating to a Markov chain, that results in the sum:

$$\sum^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{N-1}{i(N-i)}$$

For the expected time until reaching the $N^{th}$ state from $0$.

The question asks to show that for large N, the expected time is approximately $2\log{N}$, but I'm not sure how to get this from the above sum. Is there an identity that leads to that result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn it into an integral
$$\sum^{N-1}_{i=1} \frac{N-1}{i(N-i)} \approx \int_1^{N}\frac {N-1}{x(N-x)}dx$$
Now do partial fractions on the integral
$$\int_1^{N}\frac {N-1}{x(N-x)}dx=\int_1^N\left(\frac {N-1}{Nx}+\frac {N-1}{N(N-x)}\right)dx$$ and each term integrates to $\frac {N-1}N\log N$, the second by recognizing it is the same integral as the first done backwards.

Comment: Thanks! Why is the integral from 1 to N rather than N-1? I suppose it doesn't really matter for large N?

Comment: Because each term $i$  in your sum is represented by the range $[i,i+1)$ in my integral, so your term $N-1$ runs from $N-1$ to $N$.  The conversion looks at your sum as one of the Riemann sums evaluating the integral and using the left hand endpoints of each interval

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Comment: Depending on the standards of the course you are in, you may be expected to justify that the error of the approximation is small enough.  If you draw a graph your sum is a bunch of stairsteps and the integral is a curvy line through some of the corners.  The discrepancy is small, but you may be expected to show that it does not dominate.